# How can I create a table that uses an equation to average data from another table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that contains data from repeated experiments (for example, site A has one sample, and the lab processed the sample three times obtaining slightly different values). I need to average these results in a separate table, but what I have read on the Microsoft support site is that a query that pulls data into another table with a calculated field is not possible on Access.

Can I query multiple data points from one table into a single calculated field in another table? Thank you.

UPDATE

I ended up doing a lot of manual adjustments of the file format to create a calculated field in the existing table that averages each sites data, so my problem is, for my current purposes, solved. However I would still like to understand. Following up with you both, I think the problem was that I had repeated non-unique IDs between rows when I probably should have made data columns with unique variable names so that I could query each variable name for an average.

So, instead of putting each site separately on the y axis, I formatted it by putting the sample number for each site on the x-axis:

I was able to at least create a calculated field using this second format in order to create an average value for each site.

Would have there been a way to write a query using the first method? Luckily, my data set was not at all very hefty, so I could handle a reformat manually, but if the case were with thousands of data entries, I couldn't have done that.

Also, here is the link to the site I mentioned originally https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3.

Thanks all.

Comment: It is not necessary to save calculated aggregate data to table - just use the aggregate query as a table. Edit question to show sample data as text (not images) if you need more assistance.

Comment: It is usually bad design to save aggregate calcs - they can get 'out of sync' with raw data - which is why it is deliberately difficult. However, VBA can accomplish update of existing records with aggregate values.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the support site page? Based on what you wrote, that site is just plain wrong. A query is the only way to add calculated fields to data that is queried from several other tables.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt, I think OP wants to save calculated aggregate data to existing record. UPDATE query cannot save data from an aggregate (GROUP BY) query, which is probably what that site was advising.

Comment: @June7 I'm tracking now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That link has nothing to do with calculations in query nor aggregation of data. Again, no, a query cannot save aggregate calculation into existing record. Can INSERT new records into table. How do you perform average calc in table Calculated type field? If you show sample raw data and desired output, might be able to provide solution. This calculated data is for a graph?